# CriteriaBuilder boolean comparison

Tags: jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I'm currently doing like this.

```java
final CriteriaBuilder builder = ...;
final boolean flag = ...;

if (flag) {
    builder.isTrue(expression);
} else {
    builder.isFalse(expression);
}
```

Can I use it like this?

```java
builder.equals(expression, flag);
```

Is this try won't have any problem? Say null for expression or something.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suppose you implied using `CriteriaBuilder`'s `equal` method. In this case yes, you can use it as follows:

```
builder.equal(expression, flag);
```

And this is equivalent to:

```
if (flag) {
  builder.isTrue(expression);
} else {
  builder.isFalse(expression);
}
```

But be aware that if you use `Hibernate` as `JPA` provider the former implementation will throw NPE in case `expression==null` is true while the latter one won't.

Comment: When using this isTrue or isFalse I see that Hibernate is adding a =1 to my query . e.g. SELECT * FROM USER WHERE IS_ACTIVE = 1; Is there anyway that when using isTrue I can tell Hibernate to leave that =1 off as mySQL will treat boolean columns as true in condition by default? This additional =1 check is adding over 2 seconds to query when I have a 1 second SLA.

Comment: To avoid NPE you can `builder.equal(builder.coalesce(expression, false), flag);`: this way NULL expression will be treated as FALSE.